# Unable to Bind XML file to a drop down list in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml

i am quite new to asp.net
I downloaded this xll file with is like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<countries author="Banmeet Singh" title="Country, State-Province selections"
date="2008-Feb-05">
  <country name="Afghanistan">
    <state>Badakhshan</state>
    <state>Badghis</state>
    <state>Baghlan</state>
    <state>Balkh</state>
    <state>Bamian</state>
    <state>Farah</state>
    <state>Faryab</state>
    <state>Ghazni</state>
    <state>Ghowr</state>
    <state>Helmand</state>
    <state>Herat</state>
    <state>Jowzjan</state>
    <state>Kabol</state>
    <state>Kandahar</state>
```

And the list goes on.
Now i want to display the countries in drop down list,
 so here is the code in c# on page_load

```
     DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

        myDataSet.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("xml/country_state.xml"));
        DropDownList1.DataSource = myDataSet;
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "country";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Ir gives this error
:- `DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'state'`
**Please tell me what i am doing wrong**. thanks

Ok updates, here is the html code

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>



    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, show us the html part of the DropDownList1

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your list to the `Table` within the `Dataset`

So your binding should be more like this (assuming you only have 1 table in the `Dataset`')

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables[0];
```

Also try binding to the column like so:

```
DropDownList1.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["country"].ToString();
```

Finally - you don't need to `Bind()` twice, just once. After setting all your properties is usually a good place.

with regards to your `state` error - Are you sure you posted all of the code involved? this should only come about if you're trying to access 'state' and it doesn't look like you are from what you have posted.